# i am trying to insert arrow function in the js

Tags: reactjs

ERROR
[eslint]
src\components\Subscribe.js
Line 10:9:  'Buttonchange' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
 Buttonchange=()=>{
            this.setState({
                msg:" Thanks for Subscribing",
                btnmsg:"Subscribed "
            })
```

trying to include this function in the js file but its showing this error

Comment: const buttonChange

Answer (score 0):

I think Buttonchange is not defined because what you meant to type is `button onChange`. You should add more context to your code snippet.

By the way, arrow functions dont have a `this` binding ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)), so when you fix your current error, I think that will break too. Look into using a normal function definition if you want to write `this.setState(...)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Anyway, your code snippet should look something like this:

```js
<button onChange=function ...
```